# convert a zip file to base64 using vbs in UFT

Tags: vbscript, zip, base64

I have a requirement of converting a zip file from my local machine to base64.

1. Get/Read the path name from the excel sheet row
2. convert the file in the path (zip file) to base 64 string
3. Copy the base 64 value to next column in the excel sheet.

Tried a few but did not work.

**Current Code:**

```
Dim inByteArray, base64Encoded

inByteArray = readBytes("F:path/file.zip")
base64Encoded = encodeBase64(inByteArray)

Private Function readBytes(file)
    Dim inStream
    ' ADODB stream object used
    Set inStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ' open with no arguments makes the stream an empty container 
    inStream.Open
    inStream.Type = TypeBinary
    inStream.LoadFromFile(file)
    readBytes = inStream.Read()
End Function

Private Function encodeBase64(bytes)
    Dim DM, EL
    Set DM = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    ' Create temporary node with Base64 data type
    Set EL = DM.CreateElement("tmp")
    EL.DataType = "bin.base64"
    ' Set bytes, get encoded String
    EL.NodeTypedValue = bytes
    encodeBase64 = EL.Text
End Function
```

Error 1 in the line `inStream.type = TypeBinary`:

> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Error 2 in the line `readBytes = inStream.Read()`:

> Operation is not allowed in this context.

Error 3 in the line `EL.NodeTypedValue = bytes`:

> Type mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got the code from [here](https://ghads.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/vbscript-readwrite-binary-encodedecode-base64/), but didn't include

```
Const TypeBinary = 1
```

Adding this will avoid the "Arguments are of the wrong type ..." error.

Perhaps **careful** copy will solve your other problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that :)

Further for excel sheet read and write I used the below code which helped in achieving my target. Thank you

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("F:\path")

Set ws = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
rowcount = ws.usedrange.rows.count

for j = 1 to rowcount

                fieldvalue = ws.cells(j,1)


               inByteArray = readBytes(fieldvalue)
               base64Encoded = encodeBase64(inByteArray)
               ws2.cells(j,1) = base64Encoded   
next
```